# Clustered event driven Java application - Should I use Websockets or polling?

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I'm creating a monitor application that monitors the activities of a user. There are four elements in my system[image]:

`EventCatcher`: The `EventCatcher` is responsible for catching all the events that happen in a subsystem and pushes the data to the `EventHandler`. Based from observation, there is an average of 10 events per second that is being pushed to the `EventHandler`. Some events are UserLogin, UserLogout.

`EventHandler`: The `EventHandler` is a singleton class that handles all the incoming events from the `EventCatcher`. It also keeps track of all the logged in users in the system. So, whenever the `EventHandler` receives a UserLogin event, the `User` object is extracted from the event and is stored in a `HashMap`. When a UserLogout event is received, that `User` object will be remove from the `HashMap`. This class also maintains a `Set` of all active Websocket sessions because everytime an event has occurred, I would want to inform all the open sessions that a particular event happened.

`Websocket Endpoint`: This is just a simple Java class annotated with `@ServerEndpoint`.

`Clients`: The system I will be building is for internal (company) use only. At production, at most, there will only be around 5 - 10 clients. All the clients will be receiving the same information every time an event has occurred.

So right now I am trying to convince my supervisor that Websockets is the way to go, however, my supervisor finds it really unnecessary because a simple polling solution would do the trick.

His points are:

1. We don't really need up-to-date information by the millisecond. We can poll every second.
2. If I was to maintain a list of open WebSocket sessions, how would that work in a clustered environment (we use a load balancer)
3. If I plan to send information to the client every time an event (UserLogin, UserLogout) has occurred, I should be able to just send small updates to all WebSocket sessions - meaning, I can't be sending a whole JSON dump of everything. So that means, for every WebSocket instance, I would have to maintain another Set of Users and properly maintain it to mirror the Set contained in the `EventHandler`.

What my supervisor suggests is that I lose the WebSocket and just convert it to a simple Servlet and let the clients poll every second to receive the entire JSON dump.

In this scenario, should I stick with WebSockets? Or should I just poll?

The main advantage, as far as I've read, of Websockets vs. polling is that by using Websockets, you will have a persistent connection from client to server. HTTP is not really meant for real-time data.

Also, polling requires sending an HTTP request every time and every request comes with HTTP headers. If an HTTP request header contains 800 bytes, then that's 48kb sent per minute per client. With a WebSocket, this isn't problem.

But then again, we won't really have a lot of active clients. We're not concerned about third parties sniffing our requests because this system is for company use only - internal use! And I believe my supervisor wants something simple and reliable.

I am fine with either way. I just want to be sure whether I'm using the right tool for the job.

Additional question: If WebSockets is the way to go, is there any reason why I should consider polling?

Comment: Is your network such that you are actually concerned with 48Kb/client per minute? That's an awfully low data rate to really be concerning. WebSockets are the shiny new toy, but polling would seem to be fine for this sort of application. Maintaining sessions in a clustered environment would seem to introduce the potential for additional complication and failure points (what if one of the cluster members fails?). With a simple web service that a client polls periodically, you wouldn't have to worry about session management. My two cents...

Comment: @pens-fan-69 This is what my supervisor was considering. There were just so many articles and blogs stating that WebSockets is the future. Apparently, it looks like that I just need a simple solution for this application and polling would suffice. Thank you for your input! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The entire purpose of [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is to efficiently support continuing connections between client and server.

I’m not clear on how you are implementing your app. If this is a web app running in a Servlet environment leveraging WebSocket support in the web server, be aware that you need to use recent versions of the Servlet container. For example, with Tomcat you must use either version 8 or the latest updates to version 7.

And of course the web browser must have support for WebSocket.

Be aware that WebSocket is still a new technology that has been changing and evolving in both the specs and the implementations.

## Atmosphere

You may want to consider using the [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere) framework. Atmosphere supports multiple techniques of [Push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) including WebSocket & Comet.

The [Vaadin](https://www.vaadin.com/) web-app framework leverages Atmosphere to provide automatic support for Push in your app. By default, WebSocket is automatically attempted first. If WebSocket is not available, Vaadin+Atmosphere falls back automatically to the other techniques including polling.